# change img-tag to video-tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, video, replace, tags

as seen in the title i want to change an img-tag to a video-tag. I'm making a slideshow and at the end of the ArrayList there's a video. But in the html-code I used an img-tag to show the images. Now when the Array-List comes to the video I want to change the img into video.

**HTML-Code:**

```
 <div id="content1" class="section"> 
      <div class="menucont" >
                      Commercial Shoot for FILA, Lookbook SS2014</br>
                      Styled by Stephen Mann.</br>
                      Assisted by PYO KHANG.</br>
                      Models: Katja, ELITE MODELS</br>
      <div id="zahl1"> 1 / 20 </div>
      <div class="pfeil" onClick="zurueck1();"> < </div>
      <div class="pfeil" onClick="weiter1();"> > </div>
    </div>


    <div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg01.jpg" id="imgcont1" class="imgcontstyle" onClick="weiter1();">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS-Code:**

```
pic1 = new Array();
pic1[1] = new Image(); pic1[1].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg01.jpg";
pic1[2] = new Image(); pic1[2].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg02.jpg";
pic1[3] = new Image(); pic1[3].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg03.jpg";
pic1[4] = new Image(); pic1[4].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg04.jpg";
pic1[5] = new Image(); pic1[5].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg05.jpg";
pic1[6] = new Image(); pic1[6].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg06.jpg";
pic1[7] = new Image(); pic1[7].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg07.jpg";
pic1[8] = new Image(); pic1[8].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg08.jpg";
pic1[9] = new Image(); pic1[9].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg09.jpg";
pic1[10] = new Image(); pic1[10].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg10.jpg";
pic1[11] = new Image(); pic1[11].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg11.jpg";
pic1[12] = new Image(); pic1[12].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg12.jpg";
pic1[13] = new Image(); pic1[13].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg13.jpg";
pic1[14] = new Image(); pic1[14].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg14.jpg";
pic1[15] = new Image(); pic1[15].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg15.jpg";
pic1[16] = new Image(); pic1[16].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg16.jpg";
pic1[17] = new Image(); pic1[17].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg17.jpg";
pic1[18] = new Image(); pic1[18].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg18.jpg";
pic1[19] = new Image(); pic1[19].src = "../img/2lucy/serie/lucy_bytimothyschaumburg19.jpg";
pic1[20] = new Image(); pic1[20].src = "../img/2lucy/video/lucy.mp4";

var b=1;

function weiter1()
{
  ++b;
  if (b>20) b=1;
    document.getElementById('imgcont1').src = pic1[b].src;
    document.getElementById('zahl1').innerHTML = [b] + " / 20";
}

function zurueck1()
{
--b;
  if (b<1) b=20;
    document.getElementById('imgcont1').src = pic1[b].src;
    document.getElementById('zahl1').innerHTML = [b] + " / 20";
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Max

PS: I am very new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005255/using-javascript-to-change-the-very-type-of-tag) helped me out.  Long story short, you can't change the type of a tag.  But you *can* make a new element of the proper type, put it in the right place, and remove the old element.  You can even take the children nodes of the old element and drop them into the new element.