# Javascript regular expression issue - run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting a Javascript minification error saying:

```
(9,8617-8631): run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression: /\<br>(.*?)/ig
(9,8757-8776): run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression: /\<p>(.*?)\<\/p>/ig
```

The javascript where these occur is:

```
$htmlPattern =  [
                    /\<br>(.*?)/ig,
                    /\<br\/>(.*?)/ig
                ];

$htmlReplace = [
                    '<p>$1</p>',
                    '<p>$1</p>'
                ];
```

...and...

```
$htmlContent = $htmlContent.replace(/\<p>(.*?)\<\/p>/ig, '<div>$1</div>');
```

Can anyone see what the problem is with the regular expressions noted?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Doing justice to the good old maxim ["don't parse HTML with regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1282023): If you want to replace an element's tagname, you could consider using [jQuery's replaceWith()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3435890/1282023). Or, if it must be pure JS, have a look at [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4005685/1282023).

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't need two patterns. Just make the br's `/` optional, perhaps with optional space also: `/<br[\s\/]*>(.*?)/ig` or `/<br\b[^>]*>(.*?)/ig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted that first backslash in those expressions, they must be escaped:

```
$htmlPattern =  [
                    /\\<br>(.*?)/ig,
                    /\\<br\/>(.*?)/ig
                ];
```

Unless that was an attempt to escape the `<`, which is not necessary. In that case, simply remove the backslash:

```
$htmlPattern =  [
                    /<br>(.*?)/ig,
                    /<br\/>(.*?)/ig
                ];
```